# How to sort assembly names in the code coverage results?

Tags: continuous-integration, mstest, code-coverage

Is it possible somehow to sort assembly names by name or by % of covered blocks in the code coverage results on the build's Summary view?

[image: My instrumented binaries list I want to change.]

It is hard to find specific assembly without sorting when we have 100+ assemblies in the instrumented binaries list.

I tried to sort all assemblies in the "servertestrun.testrunconfig" file used for MSTest (All assemblies under Regular tag), but it was not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the assemblies in the code coverage window. For that, you should do the following steps.

1. Click "View Test Results" in the build summary which will open the results file in test result window.
2. In test results window there is a gesture to show the code coverage results.
3. In code coverage window, you can sort the assemblies and can view full details of code coverage.

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm trying to find a solution how to sort it directly on the Build summary view without creating custom view. It seems to be the only one solution for this instead of opening the results file in the Visual Studio.